# How to uninstall Ganache GUI in Ubuntu?

Tags: ganache

I removed ganache, ganache-cli from terminal.
`npm ls ganache` shows nothing
But still I can see ganache gui. I want to remove the ganache gui fully. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured out. Ganache GUI is basically executable which run directly. Simply delete that exe and download new. Done.

Incase you are unable to find exe location - In Ubuntu desktop shortcut are saved at location /home/<user>/.local/share/applications. Check the respective file and you'll get actual location of exe.

Comment: Hi @Sagar Khatale, Welcome! Thanks to share your solution with the community. Please, could you check your question as resolved? Congrats!